# advanced-custom-fields the_field function not work in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to use the the_field(); function in wordpress but did't work 
also I tried to use the get_field(); function  and same problem what I can do

```
<?php the_field('contact_form_short_code'); ?>
```

I am using  advanced-custom-fields plugin the free version

Comment: Debugging advice:  try replacing that code with echo 'hello'; and make sure that you see 'hello' where you expect to.  If you don't the problem isn't in your acf code.  If it does work, I would check to make sure that you typed the name of the field correctly.  If that checks out, I'd check to make sure that you are actually inside the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`the_field('contact_form_short_code')` will try to get the field info from the current post in the loop. If you're not currently in a loop it will look to the current page/post.

If you want to reference a post from outside the loop you must specify the post ID, eg: `the_field('contact_form_short_code', $post_id)`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Check if your field group location points to your template, taxonomy or custom post type, after that try to use echo to call your field.

Check this link [www.advancedcustomfields.com](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

Comment: the fields group linked to the home page which has custom template

Comment: Don't forget to change template into your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the shortcode (contact_form_short_code) specified in the admin panel via a custom field (ACF), you need to use the **do_shortcode();** function.
In your case, the code looks like this:

```
<?php
//In the admin panel we fill the shortcode of the contact form, for example CF7.
//[contact-form-7 id="1" title="Form"] 
$cform = get_field('contact_form_short_code', $post_id);
//Output of shortcode
echo do_shortcode($cform);?>
```